# Short for of creating an object from 2 variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a short form of doing such operation:

```
function doObject(key, value){
   let object = {};
   return object[key] = value;
}
```

**UPD**: forget about function, I use it just to isolate scope and provide to params **key** and **value**. I don't need to implement the function but logic that it does

Answer (score 3):

```
const doObject = (key, value) => ({[key]: value});
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^ ^^^^^
//               1               2 3
```

1. **[Arrow function](https://devdocs.io/javascript/functions/arrow_functions)** syntax
2. Wrapping with braces allows you to return an object literal without the extended syntax. (Otherwise, it thinks the `{}` are the block delimiters.
3. **[Computed object literal property key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)**.

Comment: Important to note this is ES2015 syntax, and might not yet be supported across the board.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:ecmascript-6].

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for the object:

```
function doObject(key, value){
   return {
       [key]: value
   };
}
```

Comment: The correct term is "computed property name".